# Access ParamMap

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, router

It seems I don't know how to access a param in my route and I can't figure out why.
I have the following route structure:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'foo',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      // some sibling paths
      {
        path: 'odl/:id',
        component: OdlMainComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'details',
            component: OdlDetailComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'phases',
            component: OdlPhasesComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ViewsRoutingModule {}
```

Now I'm inside my OdlMainComponent and it looks like I can't get that id inside my route.
I tried the following solutions without any success:

```
constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this._odlId = +this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // or
    this._odlId = +this._route.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // or
    this._odlId = +this._route.root.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you getting in this, did you try to console.log?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question right. Referring to  my route structure listed above I'm getting this inside OdlMainComponent and each child-route.
Logging this._odlId gets me 0 in each case.
Logging each paramMaps shows me it's empty

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

Take a look at code:

```
_params: object;

constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute
) { 
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => this._params = params);
    // console.log(this._params['id']);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._odlId = + this._params['id'];
}
```

I hope that you'll find this useful, this is the way how I do it. 
Maybe someone has a better solution than this.